# Java: Problematic System.out in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, system.out

Is there any option to block logging System.out.println in log4j? I'm working with very old code and getting rid of all the occurrences is a not go (most of the code is compiled).

All System.out's are logged as [DEBUG][root]

Here is the configuration i'm using:

```
<appender name="Console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}][%-5p][%c] - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</root>
```